# What is the benefit and a common real-world practical application of using Tuples in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, tuples, vb.net-2010

I have read about the [`Tuples`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) provided with the coming-out of the new .NET Framework features, and still am I wondering about how it could be useful in *real-world* enterprise applications.

Can one give me a brief explanation along with a simple but *real-world* code sample?

Thanks! =)

Comment: You have a lot of questions like these, don't you? :)

Comment: The "What is the benefit and a common real-world practical application..." questions are getting old.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Yes I have. Sorry. I only wish to get up and running in .NET 4.0, using the benefits it provides. Even though I have read about these features, sometimes I can't get a grab on it. I find it easier when some probably more experienced and perhaps better bring their vision or understanding of the thing.

Comment: @Justin Niessner: Sorry! I tried recently to group my questions into only one big question, and it has gotten closed for being too broad. I have been suggested to post a question for each feature instead. So do I. =S

Comment: I find that podcasts serve really well as an "introduction to features," and a way to survey technologies and understand in a high-level way where they are used.  HanselMinutes and DotNetRocks are especially good.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Thanks for this hint about DotNetRocks and HanselMinutes. I had never heard of them before. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tuples aren't currently all that large a benefit in C#, because there isn't any neat syntax for them. However, the concept is very common in functional languages such as F# (new to .NET 4.0).

So, if you're writing part of your application in F# or if you're using libraries written in F#, you might run into them. If you're using only C#, I'd say you're better off using [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). They allow you to name the various properties, whereas they will be called `Item1` through `ItemX` using tuples. Not very descriptive.

Of course, if you want to return multiple values (with different types) from a method, using anonymous types isn't an option, in which case using tuples might be a decent solution if you're making something quick and dirty.

Comment: Shame that there's no sugar for them in C#, because yeah, they are really useful to have sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

A tuple is just a simple way to return multiple values from a function.

Comment: Don't think this was the main purpose for creating them

Comment: @Kamarey: What is the main purpose for creating them? @Thorarin says it is more likely to be used while coding F# than C#. It also seems to be close to the anonymous types, to my understanding.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller: I agree with Thorarin, so he got my +1.

Answer (score 4):

The best would be easy multiple value returning, so coding performance would be an answer. It's also quite readable.

I.e:

```
return new Tuple<int, string, char>(1, "some string", 10.00);
```

Versus something like

```
public class ReturnMany
{
   public int intValue { get; set; }
   public string strValue { get; set; }
   public decimal decValue { get; set; }
}

return new ReturnMany() { intValue = 1, strValue = "some string", decValue = 10.00 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Tuples in .NET are immutable so they're also an easy way to pass a bunch of values around threads. I'm currently using tuples with Retlang and they're great for use with this type of library.

Comment: Immutability could indeed be an advantage. Anonymous types can't be immutable, so the only other option would be handcrafting a class or struct.